# #1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'question_content' used in key specification without a key length

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-design

```
ALTER TABLE `aws_testquestion`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`),
  ADD KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  ADD KEY `update_time` (`update_time`),
  ADD KEY `add_time` (`add_time`),
  ADD KEY `published_uid` (`published_uid`),
  ADD KEY `answer_count` (`answer_count`),
  ADD KEY `agree_count` (`agree_count`),
  ADD KEY `question_content` (`question_content`),
  ADD KEY `lock` (`lock`),
  ADD KEY `thanks_count` (`thanks_count`),
  ADD KEY `anonymous` (`anonymous`),
  ADD KEY `popular_value` (`popular_value`),
  ADD KEY `best_answer` (`best_answer`),
  ADD KEY `popular_value_update` (`popular_value_update`),
  ADD KEY `against_count` (`against_count`),
  ADD KEY `is_recommend` (`is_recommend`),
  ADD KEY `weibo_msg_id` (`weibo_msg_id`),
  ADD KEY `received_email_id` (`received_email_id`),
  ADD KEY `unverified_modify_count` (`unverified_modify_count`),
  ADD KEY `chapter_id` (`chapter_id`),
  ADD KEY `sort` (`sort`[...]
```

I got this error:

```
#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'question_content' used in key specification without a key length
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `question_content`? How is PHP related? Seems like a `mysql` question. Likely what you need to look at is https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210403/how-do-you-index-a-text-column-in-mysql You also shouldn't just index every column on your table if that is what you are doing here.

Comment: okey thanks for answer i understand now

Answer (score 0):

- It is bad practice, for several reasons, to "index every column".
- `TEXT` and `BLOB` cannot be indexed, except with a "prefix" index, which is rarely useful.
- Indexing true/false columns is rarely helpful.
- It is best to design the indexes based on the popular `SELECTs`.  Show us a few of them.
- There is a limit of how many indexes a table will handle.  (Rarely is it practical to have more than 5.  The hard limit is something like 64.)